# changing the costume color of navbar-default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> myBLOG </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_page.css" />

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="nav navbar-nav">
         <ul>

         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and I have a css with codes :

```
.navbar-default {
   background-color: #F583E4;
}
```

but it doesnt change the default color of navbar. 
am I doing right? or this is wrong, and if its wrong can sum1 help me to code how to change a navbar-default color?

thank you

Comment: It would help if you could replicate your scenario in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the !important tag? It's not good practice to use this all the time, but it does help identify cause of issues.

Alternatively you can edit the bootstrap.css file, line 4498 of the latest version (or just ctrl-f "navbar-default") shows the background-color setting. Simply change the value there.

As displayed in bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```